# how to know the current Zoom level in D3.js

Tags: javascript, events, graph, d3.js, zooming

I have a problem since a few days. I have a graph and when I use [Zoom Behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#wiki-zoom) it works, but I need to know when I reach maximum zoom to load new given

```
// Specifies the zoom scale's allowed range, [min, max]
d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).scaleExtent([1,10]).on("zoom", draw)
```

See my code
http://jsfiddle.net/albanlopez/D4MRP/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rect.call(zm=d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).scaleExtent([1,10]).on("zoom", draw));
```

After a new test i have the answer :

```
var currentZoom = d3.event.scale;
```

But only available/readable in the **draw()** function called by **.on("zoom", draw)**

```
rect.call( zm = d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).scaleExtent([1,10]).on("zoom", draw));

function draw() {
    // trace l'axe X
    svg.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxis);
    // trace l'axe Y
    svg.select("g.y.axis").call(yAxis);
    // trace la courbe
    svg.select("path.line").attr("d", line);

    console.log(zm.scale(), zm.translate()); // , zm.translate[1] = Y
    console.log(d3.event.scale, d3.event.translate[0]); // , d3.event.translate[1] = Y
}
```

Answer (score 16):

In the draw function the current event will have the zoom level (d3.event.scale as you mentioned). Also if you keep the behaviour around like:

```
var zm = d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).scaleExtent([1,10]).on("zoom", draw);
```

Then you can find the current zoom level by calling:

```
zm.scale();
```

Comment: ok, it's works **console.log(zm.scale(), zm.translate());** but exclusively in the drawing function()

Comment: It should work anywhere provided you have access to the zm variable in the scope or the closure. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/Dn9Dn/)

Answer (score 11):

As of D3 v4 there are two documented ways of retrieving the zoom state. To quote d3/d3-zoom README (under Zoom Transforms):

> To retrieve the zoom state, use event.transform on a current zoom
>   event within a zoom event listener (see zoom.on), or use
>   d3.zoomTransform for a given node.

https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom-transforms

Answer (score 2):

As of today (d3.v5), the way to check the zoom level within the closure is by looking at this attribute:

> d3.event.transform.k