# How to zoom + pan ellipses in D3 using zoom behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, pan, panning

I have recently applied a pan + zoom based on the D3 example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957

This works great for polygons, lines, circles, but not ellipses.  When I pan + zoom the ellipse and scale the rx and ry values, respectively the new rx/ry values don't change as I would expect. The ellipse greatly reshapes and sometimes even disappears (rx/ry go negative).

I've looked at other similar examples online and they also don't work with ellipses.

Here is a JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/44VYK/

I don't think this is an issue with D3, and my gut says I've missed something fundamental with the example and with D3's zoom behavior.

If anyone can help and clarify what I've missed it would be really appreciated.  I suspect it's a simple oversight, but I'm stomped.

Here's the jsFiddle code:

```
    var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var data = [{x:300,y:300, rx:100, ry:50, theta:45}];
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([0, 1]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([0, 1]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([.2, 8]).on("zoom", zoom));

var r2d = 180.0 / Math.PI;

var ellipse = svg.selectAll("ellipse")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("ellipse")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.x);})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.y);})
    .attr("rx", function(d) {return x(d.rx);})
    .attr("ry", function(d) {return y(d.ry);})
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'rotate('+ x(d.theta * r2d) + ' ' + x(d.x) + ' ' + y(d.y) + ')';
     });

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("fill", "yellow")
.attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.x);})
.attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.y);})
.attr("r", function(d) {return 30;});

function zoom() {
    ellipse
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.x);})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.y);})
    .attr("rx", function(d) {return x(d.rx);})
    .attr("ry", function(d) {return y(d.ry);})
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'rotate('+ x(d.theta * r2d) + ' ' + x(d.x) + ' ' + y(d.y) + ')';
     });

    circle
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.x);})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.y);})
    .attr("r", function(d) {return 30;});

}
```

Comment: Found another post that answered my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147136/how-to-know-the-current-zoom-level-in-d3-js